# Why should we sometimes use --+ instead of -- in SQL injection to comment the rest of the query?

Tags: http, sql-injection, mysql

I have encountered some websites that when I used `--` to comment the rest of the query it didn't work, but when I tried `--+` it worked.

In the [MySQL official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comments.html) there is no such thing as `--+` and we only have `--` and two other ways.

Why does this happen (in detail)? I want to know exactly why this works sometimes and `--` doesn't, and why there is no `--+` for comments in the MySQL man page?

Comment: I suppose your question is more related to *HTTP* than to SQL...

Comment: @YourCommonSense i had no idea its related to HTTP and not SQL, so why this happens?

Comment: You can also use # which doesn't need a space after

Answer (score 59, accepted):

From the documentation:

> From a --  sequence to the end of the line. In MySQL, the --  (double-dash) comment style requires the second dash to be **followed by at least one whitespace** or control character (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on). This syntax differs slightly from standard SQL comment syntax, as discussed in Section 1.8.2.4, “'--' as the Start of a Comment”.

(emphasis mine)

Many URL decoders treat `+` as a space.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84883/discussion-on-answer-by-androlgenhald-why-should-we-sometimes-use-instead-of).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL requires a blank space followed by the double dashes like "-- " and a URL can't contain blank spaces but the + sign can be used as blank space. That's why these comments are followed up by "+".